# Save recorded file to ipod Library path

Tags: iphone

Hope you all are fine and also in one of your best mood.

I need your help to know one thing in iPhone, if You know then please share it with me and lot's of other phone developer.

I am developing an application in which i need to record a Sound and Add it to iPod Library.

I finished with recording file, but now issue arise here is  How do I save this song to iPod Path or iPod Directory.

I am not able to add a recorded file to iPod.

I think if we have a path for ipod Library, then using file manager i can store that file to that path.(I guess this thing but not sure.)

SO If you know path of iPod Library ten please tell me, and also how do i write file  to this path.

May be this issue bit easy, but due to i am newbie, I Don't know how to do that.

So please help me to solve this problem.

Looking forwards for your replies.

Thank You,

Regards,

Arun Thakkar.

Answer (score 2):

Applications in the iPhone have a sandboxed access to the file system, which means you can't directly write a file into the iTunes library on the device. You can only write files in your application's space on the file system. So if you want to modify the iTunes library, you need for there to be some system API to do that. There *is* iTunes library API, but it only lets you read the library, not write to it; in short, you can't do that.